# Copied IntelliJ project machine A to B, but it won't build on B

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have IntelliJ, Scala and SBT at work (Win8) and on my laptop (OSX).  I've never had a problem like this before.  I'm stuck in a hotel because of weather, and I have a copy of my IDEA project on my laptop.  I tried building the project on my laptop, and it failed with the message below.  As far as I know I have all the dependent JARs, the latest plugins, etc.  I don't think I'm missing anything.  But I'm mystified how something so simple could eat up time that could be spent programming while I try to figure out what went wrong after zipping and copying an IntelliJ project from one machine to another.

```
Error:scalac: Error: xsbt.CompilerInterface
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.CompilerInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:117)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:57)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:52)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerCache$$anon$2.apply(CompilerCache.scala:50)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: How you are importing ?

Comment: @singhakash Good question. I select Open Project from the IntelliJ menu rather than Import Project.  I'll try that.

Comment: remember import as sbt project also check https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0

Comment: @singhakash Error while importing SBT project:
...at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
...at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
See complete log in /private/var/folders/_y/kfydh5v48xj9sj001s77qyj00000gn/T/sbt0.log which said:
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.8: not found

Meanwhile, build.sbt has:
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.8"

Comment: update your question its difficult to read

Comment: @singhakash Thanks for the Play Application suggestion. Actually this is not a Play Application. I'm only using the Play JARs that support JSON. I saw other people do that, and I was able to get that to work fine on my work machine. At work sbt can resolve libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.8" just fine, but not in a hotel room on a different machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72075/discussion-between-gknauth-and-singhakash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- use "Import project" instead of File|Open. Select sbt project
- ensure you have access to internet
- build the project first on the command line . e.g

  ```
   sbt compile package
  ```

or

```
     sbt compile assembly
```

- rebuild the project in the IDE (Yes painful, but it is a known bug)

Get back here if you still encounter issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem with updating IDEA to version 14. Try removing the JDK from IDEA and adding it again. It should work.